# Laravel can't find some files

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in the middle of some work and suddenly I get this.

> Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/laravel/÷5 ication)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/public/index.php on line 34
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/laravel/÷5 ication'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/public/index.php on line 34

This error is shown on some requests that have no relation, so there is not a problem with them. This problem started showing a few hours ago

I have checked the files mentioned on the message and they are OK, based on the download I just made to make sure.

If I keep refreshing the page the file name changes. If I insist, it will end up loading my page. This process is costing me a lot of time, I'm trying to make some tests and sometimes this message shows up.

Comment: What is on line 34 of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/public/index.php`?  It looks like it may be dynamically building the file path string used in a "require" statement.  And for whatever reason, it fails to build the string correctly for some requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...you said that it happens in same pages that make requests, take a good look on your requests and try looking for something wrong.

A good tip is to use the Profile on your framework configuration. You will have a bottom bar with details about the queries executed and logs created.

I think that will help you find the problem.